# Application not quitting

Tags: vb.net, winforms, notifications, icons

I coded my application to hide and show icon in the system tray. When you click on icon and exit, my application disappear but the application still shows running in task manager. Here's my closing:

```
Private Sub Form_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    NotifyIcon1.ContextMenuStrip = ContextMenuStrip1
End sub 

Private Sub OpenWorkSheet_FormClosing(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.FormClosingEventArgs) Handles Me.FormClosing
    e.Cancel = True
    Me.Visible = False
    Me.NotifyIcon1.Visible = True
End Sub

Private Sub OpenToolStripMenuItem1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles OpenToolStripMenuItem1.Click
    Try
        NotifyIcon1.ContextMenuStrip = ContextMenuStrip1
        Me.Visible = True
        Me.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal
        NotifyIcon1.Visible = False
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try
End Sub

Private Sub ExitToolStripMenuItem_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles ExitToolStripMenuItem.Click
    Me.Visible = True
    Me.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal
    NotifyIcon1.Visible = False
    Me.Close()
    Application.Exit()
    Me.Dispose()
End Sub

Private Sub NotifyIcon1_MouseDoubleClick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs) Handles NotifyIcon1.MouseDoubleClick
    Try
        NotifyIcon1.ContextMenuStrip = ContextMenuStrip1
        Me.Visible = True
        Me.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal
        NotifyIcon1.Visible = False
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Declare a boolean variable indicating if you're closing the entire application, so that you can let your form close correctly.

This will only set `e.Cancel` to True if you are not choosing to close the entire application.

```
Dim ClosingApp As Boolean = False

Private Sub OpenWorkSheet_FormClosing(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.FormClosingEventArgs) Handles Me.FormClosing
    If ClosingApp = False Then
        e.Cancel = True
        Me.Visible = False
        Me.NotifyIcon1.Visible = True
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub ExitToolStripMenuItem_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles ExitToolStripMenuItem.Click
    ClosingApp = True
    NotifyIcon1.Visible = False
    Me.Close()
    Application.Exit()
End Sub
```

I also removed some superfluous lines, for instance disposing the form isn't necessary as **A)** You are already closing the application, all its used memory will be released. **B)** Closing the form automatically disposes it.